# Change a select option thanks to another option

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying is something pretty basic, but I can't do it because the examples I see aren't anything similar to what I'm looking for.

There are 2 `select`, one of them you choose manually and the other dynamically changes depending on the `value` of the first one.

If the `value` of the first `select` is 1, that in the second one they only appear whose `value` is 1 as well.

**I want to make it 100% JavaScript, I don't want any JQuery.**

##### `HTML.php`

```html
<select onchange="catch_value_types()" name="types" id="types">
    <option value="1">Meat</option>
    <option value="2">Fish</option>
    <option value="3">Vegetables</option>
</select>

<select name="food" id="food">
    <option value="1">Pork</option>
    <option value="1">Cow</option>
    <option value="1">Chicken</option>
    <option value="2">Sardine</option>
    <option value="2">Salmon</option>
    <option value="2">Mackerel</option>
    <option value="3">Spinach</option>
    <option value="3">Kale</option>
    <option value="3">Green peas</option>
</select>
```

##### `JavaScript.js`

```js
function catch_value_types() {
     var types_value_option = document.getElementById("types").value;

     // What should I put here?
}
```

Comment: Your second select values don't make sense - how are you going to differentiate between the repeated values?

Comment: It makes sense since the values ​​of the second select are only indicative for the options to be displayed, so if the value of the first select is 1, it should show all the value 1s of the second select. The values ​​of the second select will not be used for anything other than that work.

Comment: If you're not going to use those values from the second select later then why put them into a select? Just use a list instead. Select is only useful if you want the user to actually choose a value (and they would then expect it to be used for something afterwards)

Comment: Then shouldn't the meats be 1,2 and 3 rather than all 1 otherwise again you are only showing the ones with all the same value and therefore when it gets submitted, you won't know which one they have picked?  Maybe you need to split them out into different selects and display the correct select based on what is selected in the first dropdown rather than hiding and showing options

Comment: @ADyson No, it must be a select because the approach of the program is that, I am only teaching a part. Depending of that second select it will be another html elements that will vary thanks to that.

Comment: `Depending of that second select it will be another html elements that will vary `...in that case then, all the IDs in the second select need to be unique as Pete mentioned - otherwise you won't know which value was chosen by the user. The whole point of an ID is to _uniquely identify_ something.

Comment: @Pete The problem with this doubt is that I am showing you in a simplified way what I want. Actually, these repeated data are read from a DB and this is how it is assembled, I can do little more to remedy it except for the question posed

Comment: If you want to decide which values to show in the second select, based on the first select, then set something like a data-attribute on the options which contains the ID of the parent item. You can then use that to find all options with the relevant value in that attribute and shown them. And then you can still have unique IDs on the options so you know which was selected.

Comment: @ADyson ok, I can put and ID in that options and it will be unique, but the question is the same, I want to filter thanks to value propiety thanks to 1th select values

Comment: Well I've just described how you could do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the options and hide if value doesnot match

```js
function catch_value_types() {
  const selectedValue = document.getElementById("types").value;
  const select2 = document.getElementById("food");  
  Array.from(select2.options).forEach((node) => node.style.display = node.value === selectedValue ? "block": "none");
}
```

```html
<select onchange="catch_value_types()" name="types" id="types">
  <option value="1">Meat</option>
  <option value="2">Fish</option>
  <option value="3">Vegetables</option>
</select>

<select name="food" id="food">
  <option>Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">Pork</option>
  <option value="1">Cow</option>
  <option value="1">Chicken</option>
  <option value="2">Sardine</option>
  <option value="2">Salmon</option>
  <option value="2">Mackerel</option>
  <option value="3">Spinach</option>
  <option value="3">Kale</option>
  <option value="3">Green peas</option>
</select>
```